# My helper function is throwing errors when I try to return a string from a context object

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a controller that needs to send an email to players using an email interface I made.

In the email, I need to show the player the monster they encountered.

I'm trying to create a little helper function that returns the name of the monster.

You can see it here:

```
    private async string GetMonsterTypeName(long id)
    {
        var monsterType = _context.MonsterTypes.FindAsync(id);
        return monsterType.Name;
    }
```

But Visual Studio 2019 is now telling me that I should make the method synchronous.

However when I do that, I get an error that states:

'ValueTask' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no accessible extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'ValueTask'

But my model MonsterTypes.cs does contain a string property called 'Name'.

So I'm not sure how to fix this.

What could I do to make this right please?

Here is my updated code with suggested edits:

```
    private async Task<string> GetMonsterTypeName(long id)
    {
        var monsterType = await _context.MonsterTypes.FindAsync(id);

        return monsterType.Name;
    }
```

thank u

Comment: `await _context.MonsterTypes.FindAsync(id);`?

Comment: The return signature should be `async Task<string>`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you but will that still return the name of the monster?

Comment: The code has two errors. You need to fix both of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method should be :

```
private async Task<string> GetMonsterTypeName(long id)
{
    var monsterType = await _context.MonsterTypes.FindAsync(id);
    return monsterType.Name;
}
```

`async` doesn't make a method asynchronous, it allows you to use `await` to await an already asynchronous operation, like `FindAsync`, without blocking the current execution context.

Asynchronous methods should return a `Task` or `ValueTask`. That task is a *promise* that a value will be available at some point in the future. To get that value, you need to use `await` to await for the operation to complete.

On the other hand, why load an entire monster when you only want its name?  `FindAsync` is equivalent to `SELECT *` when you only need a simple `SELECT Name`.

In this case it's better to write :

```
private async Task<string> GetMonsterTypeName(long id)
{
    var monsterType = await _context.MonsterTypes
                                    .Where(m=>m.Id==id)
                                    .Select(m=>m.Name)
                                    .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    return monsterType;
}
```

Comment: I see...that did clear up the error in that helper function.  However, when I try to send that value to my email function, I get this: cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>' to 'string'  Because my email function is expecting a string for the name of the monster and not a task.

Comment: Did you use `await `to get the result? This is the same error the question's code has - trying to read the result without awaiting

Comment: thanks yes I did add await...I added the improved function to my original question

Comment: You didn't post how you called this method. Did you use `var name=await GeMonserTypeName(42); `or `var name=GetMonsterTypeName(42)`? I suspect you didn't use `await `when calling the method

Comment: @ Yeah I did not use await...it's working now correctly with zero errors.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have declared the function to be asynchronous, but you aren't awaiting anything:

```
private async string GetMonsterTypeName(long id)
{
    var monsterType = await _context.MonsterTypes.FindAsync(id); <-- Add await here.
    return monsterType.Name;
}
```

The rule is, if you decorate a function with `async`, then you should use `await` somewhere in the function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add await for asynchronous method :
`var monsterType = await _context.MonsterTypes.FindAsync(id);`